# Why should I bother if SDE has weak but no strong solution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I believe I understood the concepts of  weak and strong solution of a SDE. But I don't understand why should I care about strong solution. Let me put it more precisely.

Suppose a have a Brownian motion $B$ defined on a filtered proabibility space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F_t})_{t>0},\mathbb{P})$. Suppose I have the following SDE

$$dX_t=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t,$$

where $\mu(\cdot)$ and $\sigma(\cdot)$ are integrable functions.

Now suppose I have a weak, but not strong solution to this SDE. Then, if I understood correctly, having a weak solution means that if I enrich my probability space by replacing the original filtration $(\mathcal{F_t})_{t>0}$ by  some richer *admissible* filtration for the Brownian motion $B_t$, say $(\mathcal{\hat{F}_t})_{t}$, then I would get a strong solution on the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{\hat{F}_t})_{t>0},\mathbb{P})$. Importantly, the new filtration is still admissible, and therefore, it doesn't "rely on future information".

Therefore, whenever I have a weak I solution, but not strong, all I should do is assume a filtration that is "rich enough"? I guess I must have got something wrong.

Comment: If your original filtered probability space has a "meaning", e.g. you are modelling a real-world process, then you would naturally want to have a strong solution.

Comment: @user55232 : My two cents : as a rule of thumb weak solutions are sufficient if what you want is expectation calculations with no path dependency involved, but as soon as you need path-wise information, strong solutions are needed. Best regards